# Android variable not getting defined

Tags: java, android, eclipse, variables

Eclipse keeps telling me that advancedButton "cannot be resolved or is not a field" even though I've defined it just like all the other variables that I have in my class. Even if I try to replace it with another variable its gives me the same error. Any clue as to why this is happening?

```
    public void onClick(View w) {

        switch(w.getId()){
        case R.id.advancedButton:

            Intent a = new Intent(Registration.this, RegistrationAdvanced.class);
            startActivity(a);
            break;

        }
```

Entire code

```
package com.example.testing;
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.view.MenuItem;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Registration extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button dobButton, countryButton, advancedButton;

    ArrayList<String> dobList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);

        Initialize();
        PopulateDate();
        PopulateCountries();
    }

    public void Initialize(){

        dobButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dob_button);
        dobButton.setTag("1");
        dobButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        countryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.country_button);
        countryButton.setTag("2");
        countryButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        advancedButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advanced_button);
        advancedButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.advancedButton:

            Intent a = new Intent(Registration.this, RegistrationAdvanced.class);

            startActivity(a);
            break;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: show your Activity code special button

Comment: `R.id.advancedButton` is this the way you access your variables???

Comment: is that id available R.java..if not clean the project

Comment: Its not adding it to R. And when I try to manually add it it deletes it. Cleaning didn't do it.

Comment: Can you show your registration layout?

Comment: clean the project and import your R.java present with application package name

Comment: Try to import R first.

Comment: You tried manually adding the variable to R? R is autogenerated and all manual modifications are wiped at build time. Try adding to the XMLs that hold your variables (general advice).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this code

your button ID is `R.id.advanced_button` and you have written `R.id.advancedButton`

```
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.advanced_button:

        Intent a = new Intent(Registration.this, RegistrationAdvanced.class);

        startActivity(a);
        break;

    }

}
```

**Edit**

i follow naming convention like `viewType_layoutName_ViewName` So i not cofuse at the time of Writing R.id.XXXX

For example in your case my button id will like this  `R.id.btn_registration_advance` its reduce chance to mix up IDs ...

Comment: *facepalm*
That did it. Thanks. Is there any way to detect the variable of the id being clicked though?

Comment: Fantastic!! If you tell this while you are answering, there is no negative votes.

Comment: Why?  What did you change?  Why would changing the argument name fix things?

Comment: Because id references the actual xml id, not the variable.